# Reg Exp To Remove 'onclick' from HTML elements (Notepad++)

Tags: html, regex

I have a big html file (87000+ lines) and want to delete all occurrences of onclick from all elements. Two examples of what I want to catch are:

```
 1. onclick="fnSelectNode('name2',2, true);"
 2. onclick="fnExpandNode('img3','node3','/include/format_DB.asp?Index2=3');"
```

The problem is that both function names and parameters passed to them are not the same. So I need a Regular expression that matches **onclick=** + **anything** + **);"**

And I need one that works in Notepad++

Thanks for helping ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with notepad++, but what I use in vim is:

```
onclick="[^"]+"
```

Of course this depends on there being double quotes around the onclick in every case...

Comment: you didn't try this one did you... it would turn this: `<a onclick="something" href="blah">` into this: `<a >`

Comment: This regex will be extra greedy, so it will match things like this: `onclick="fnSelectNode('name2',2, true);" href="#"` in their entirety.

Comment: True, it is greedy, but fortunately in my case the onclick attribute was last in all instances. So I got the replacement I looked for. Thank anybody for your replies.

Comment: You could use the non-greedy `.*?` operator instead of `.*` if the regex engine in NP++ supports it.

Comment: I have used the .* version of that regex quite a bit - but, like Majid, the onclick was always last. But you're right, it's not really correct.

Comment: Dav, I find regex hard to understand and just fail to comprehend how .*? could stop the greediness.

Comment: Majid: `*?` is the non-greedy version of `*` in most languages. (It's not `*` + `?`, it's a single specifier.)

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will fail if you have a `"` or `'` character included within quotes escaped by a `\`. Other than that, this should do it.

```
(onclick="[^"]+")|(onclick='[^"]+')
```

Answer (score 1):

`onclick="[^"]+"` works for me, for that 2 strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with a regex:

```
/onclick=".*?"/
```

You could also use something which is DOM-aware, such as a HTML/XML parser, or even just load up jQuery:

```
$("[onclick]").removeAttr("onclick");
```

... and then copy the body HTML into a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Could

`onclick=\".+;\"`

Work?

Answer (score 0):

```
 onclick=\".*\);\"
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the trick.

```
(\s+onclick=(?:"[^"]+")|(?:'[^']+'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your file on dreamweaver, choose edit from the toolbar, select find and replace,

put onclick="[^"]+" in find field and keep replace blank

this will do the whole thing.

Enjoy